# Convert an Option of a case class into a tuple of its elements

Tags: scala, functional-programming

So I have the following case class

```
case class Order(itemName: Option[String], quantity: Option[Int])
```

And I have a variable that is an option of Order

```
val maybeOrder: Option[Order] = ???   // could be Some(...) or None
```

And I was wondering is there a more general way of doing the following? (is this so that it would work on a case class with N params)

```
maybeOrder match {
  case Some(order) => (order.itemName, order.quantity)
  case None => (None, None)
}
```

So need a nice way for the following cases for any case class:

```
Some(Order) => (itemNameOption, quantityOption)

None => (None, None)
```

Comment: `.map {Order.unapply(_).get }.getOrElse((None, None))` but yuck. Why do you want this?

Comment: @AndyHayden If your comment were an answer, it would be a better answer than what I came up with :/

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I considered adding as an answer, but I don't see a way to extend it to N tuples. Also, yikes/yuck, I think this is a case of [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/184179).

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to your question is "no", your code is pretty much as good as it gets.

Scala does not provide a generic way to create a tuple from a case class, you need to extract the elements and create a tuple from them. And other ways of parsing an `Option`, such as `fold`, create uglier code.

---

I understand that this is just an example, but your code does look rather odd. The current code can create a tuple `(None, Some(3))` which is an order for 3 nothings! Surely you really want `Option[(String, Option[Int])]` which is an optional order for an optional number of an item.

The code for that is just

```
maybeOrder.collect{ case Order(Some(i), q) => (i, q) }
```

Comment: "There is no generic way to create a tuple from a case class"...well, case classes and tuples are isomorphic, so there is no reason why this cannot be generalized. `Shapeless` for example makes that easy enough.

Comment: @mdm I have clarified the wording to say that this is specifically about what Scala provides. But if shapeless provides a way to do this then you should post an answer showing how it can be done.

Comment: @mdm Also, there are aspects of a case class that can't be replicated in a tuple (and vice versa) so they are not really isomorphic.